# Appbar gets moved when desktop area changes

Tags: c#, appbar

I've implemented a regular Appbar. However, once I unregister and register it again (i.e., ABM_REMOVE followed by ABM_NEW), the appbar form is now moved along the desktop resize as if it was a regular window, rather than move to the edge of the screen as requested by the MoveWindow call.

Trying to understand whether I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone replicate this behavior? Adding the code below, just in case. Many thanks!

```
public void RegisterBar(Form1 form1)
{
    APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
    abd.hWnd = form1.Handle;
    if (!fBarRegistered)
    {
        uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
        abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

        //+ (int)ABMsg.ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR
        uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
        fBarRegistered = true;
        ABSetPos(form1);
    }
    else
    {
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
        fBarRegistered = false;
    }
}

public void ABSetPos(Form1 form1)
{
    APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
    abd.hWnd = form1.Handle;
    abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT;

    if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT || abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
    {
        abd.rc.top = 0;
        abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
        {
            abd.rc.left = 0;
            abd.rc.right = form1.Size.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - form1.Size.Width;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        abd.rc.left = 0;
        abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
        {
            abd.rc.top = 0;
            abd.rc.bottom = form1.Size.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - form1.Size.Height;
        }
    }

    SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);

    switch (abd.uEdge)
    {
        case (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT:
            abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + form1.Size.Width;
            break;
        case (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT:
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - form1.Size.Width;
            break;
        case (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP:
            abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + form1.Size.Height;
            break;
        case (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM:
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - form1.Size.Height;
            break;
    }

    SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);
    MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top,
            abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is just the default behavior. One has to move the form between unregister and reregister to avoid the move on desktop resize.